# NodeJS, CPU intensive operation goes quite, how do I debug?

Tags: node.js

```
const runDailyUpdate = async () => {
  await fetchSomeData()
    .then(doSomeCalculations)
    .then(storeStuffInDb)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  console.log("daily update complete");
};
```

I got this function running once daily. It takes about an hour to complete. Sometimes, it just stops in the middle of it. I got throw-catch everywhere with console.logs on errors. No error message or nothing. There's no shortage of memory.

How can I debug this? Would it help to put this in a worker? If so, how can I use this code with a worker?

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth adding some kind of timeout if you don't already have one - you can use something like bluebird's [`Promise.race`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.race.html):

```
Promise.race([
  runDailyUpdate(),
  Promise.delay(TWO_HOURS).then(() => console.log("Timed out!")),
]);
```